# How to Make spelling correction for custom entity in Spacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I want to do spelling correction for Custom entity like apple , banana etc .

I created one vocal file **"testvocab.txt"** with below content
apple

banana

cherry

date

and passed that file to [ContextualSpellCheck](https://spacy.io/universe/project/contextualSpellCheck).

```
import spacy

from contextualSpellCheck import ContextualSpellCheck

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

pipeline = nlp.add_pipe("contextual spellchecker", last=True)

ContextualSpellCheck(nlp=nlp, name="my_contextual_spellchecker",vocab_path="testvocab.txt")

doc = nlp('can i buy aple')

print(doc._.outcome_spellCheck)
```

the output i am getting as below

**can i buy?**

i am expecting

**can i buy apple**.